# WPF WebBrowser control not rendering App.net correctly

Tags: c#, css, wpf, browser, rendering

I just have completed a library to access all methods of App.net https://github.com/appdotnet/api-spec and already started adding it to my client.

But in order to authorize a user I need to open a WebBrowser pointing to a subpage of http://www.app.net/. But every url within the app.net domain is rendered wrong within the WebBrowser control I use (I think it's mostly about missing CSS and maybe some JavaScript) and so I am unable to proceed.

Anyone an idea what I could change (played already with FullTrust)? Opening the same pages in the Internet Explorer works fine.

Here's my code of my simple test window:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace NymphAppNetTester
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for BrowserTest.xaml
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]

    public partial class BrowserTest : Window
    {

        [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        public BrowserTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            buttonGo_Click_1(null, null);
        }

        private void buttonGo_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            webbrowserTest.Navigate(textboxUrl.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

and the XAML

```
<Window x:Class="NymphAppNetTester.BrowserTest"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="BrowserTest" Height="478.723" Width="565.35">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="textboxUrl" Height="23" Margin="10,10,58.2,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="http://www.app.net/"/>
        <WebBrowser x:Name="webbrowserTest" Margin="10,38,10.2,10.4"/>
        <Button x:Name="buttonGo" Content="Go" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,11,10.2,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="43" Click="buttonGo_Click_1"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Oh, Windows 7 64 Bit and Internet Explorer 8 installed (company machine, can't upgrade to INternet Explorer 9)

Comment: OK, just found the quirks mode button in my IE and if I press it also the Internet Explorer renders it wrong. So the WebBrowser control is in quirks mode by default!?

Comment: Even poking in the registry like described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28VS.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation does not render it correctly for me :(

Comment: OK, I have the answer but can't post it as answer myself :(

Comment: For those searching the same: in the end http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28VS.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation was the solution - so you need to add such an entry to your registry.

I found many comments being upset about this (why don't simply have a property on the control!?) but this is the only solution. Thanks Microsoft...